# SQL fiscal quarter totals... I've already got the calendar ones

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here's the SQL query I have for the calendar year's quarterly totals

```
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(LAST_DAY) <= 13 THEN BILLABLE END) AS Q1 
,SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(LAST_DAY) >= 14 AND WEEK(LAST_DAY) <= 26 THEN BILLABLE END) AS Q2 
,SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(LAST_DAY) >= 27 AND WEEK(LAST_DAY) <= 39 THEN BILLABLE END) AS Q3
,SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(LAST_DAY) >= 40 AND WEEK(LAST_DAY) <= 53 THEN BILLABLE END) AS Q4,
Emp_Name
FROM 'emp_info' 
WHERE YEAR(LAST_DAY) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY Emp_Name
```

I need to shift it so it gives me the fiscal year (July 1 to June 30) totals.

I know when doing so the week numbers will need to start on July 1, not January 1 and there'll probably be a case statement in there somewhere.  But I can't get it to come out correctly.

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this? (eg: MSSQL, MySQL, etc?)

Comment: Also, some flavors of SQL have a `QUARTER` function (or `DATEPART` with SQL Server); they could clean up your code a bit.

Comment: So for future reference, tag your SQL questions with the flavor of SQL you are using as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd store fiscal quarters in a table. Then your queries would be dead simple. And not only would they be dead simple, it would be obvious when they were correct.

Comment: I'll probably end up doing something similar where I'll grab all the quarterly totals in the SQL statement and throw it into a PHP array and play with it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  Emp_Name,
  IF(DATE(LAST_DAY) <= DATE('2011-6-30'), YEAR(LAST_DAY) - 1, YEAR(LAST_DAY)) f_year,
  QUARTER(LAST_DAY) quarter,
  SUM(BILLABLE)
FROM
  emp_info
GROUP BY
  Emp_Name,
  f_year,
  quarter;
```

Comment: This is close, but I don't think it's coming out right.  I changed the comparison part of the if statement to look at MONTH(LAST_DAY) and see if it's equal to or less than 6 (June).  So the f_year variable is correct, but the quarters are still looking at the calendar year.  How can I make the quarter look at the same criteria that the year is and get the right number?

Comment: Yes, you can use MONTH(LAST_DAY), it is the same. What is wrong with quarter? please provide small example with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that your query doesn't divide year into 4 quarters by month? Instead of using the `WEEK()` function use `MONTH()`.

By operating on months and years (`YEAR()`) calculating sum for fiscal year will be easy.

Comment: I understand that there's an extra week in the 4th quarter, but a quarter year = 13 weeks.  However, I was unaware of the Quarter() function in MySQL, which makes the division even easier.

But I still don't know how to make it so it's split up by fiscal year.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is going to be that generally speaking, date and time functions will only work on ISO/(Other common) calendar date/time objects, but you need them to work on a company-specific fiscal calendar.

This is why [Calendar files](http://codeinet.blogspot.com/2006/08/auxiliary-calendar-table-for-sql.html) are used, as a translation between fiscal and ISO calendars.
Generate your calendar fileout for a few years in either direction, then you can join to it, restricting/grouping by fiscal year and period.  No case statements needed.

I also recommend storing most dates in your tables as actual ISO dates, then only translating/using fiscal dates when actually necessary - we have some summation tables here which are keyed off fiscal year/period, but which display shopping-behaviour data to customers (who don't know/care when our fiscal year is)...